# Swift : How to check if Facebook access token has expired?

Tags: swift, facebook-graph-api

I'm currently using

```
if FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken() != nil { 
    //Do Something
}
else {
    //Passing the access token to my server
}
```

to check if a user is already logged in. But the problem in this approach is if a user opens my app after long time the `currentAccessToken` might have expired but since it is not `nil` it will send the expired token to the server.

How can I put a check if currentAccessToken is valid or not? I'm using version `2.4` of FBSDK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may request `https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=TOKEN`

If token is not valid you will get oauth error in json response, otherwise you will get some info about user.

But better, for my mind, do the same on server side.